# Can someone help me find the private key for my bitcoin wallet?

Tags: blockchain.info, private-key

I have a Bitcoin Wallet on Blockchain and i have a imported wallet there where my bitcoin is stuck please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design, it is not possible to determine the private key for arbitrary addresses.

If you do not have a wallet file, seed phrase, or other form of keys that lead to that address, no one can help you.

If someone asked you to transfer Bitcoin to a watch only address claiming it will be accessible by you, you have been scammed.

Comment: where can i find my wallet file

Comment: @Praveen: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=wallet+file